# Core data, search for objects based on objects own property

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I have an NSManagedObject, foo that stores the NSDate it was created. It also has another field, lifespan which store how many seconds the object is valid for.  Each foo can have a different lifespan value. Is it possible to return all foos who have not exceed their lifespan?  I'm not sure how to express that in my NSPredicate or if it is even possible?

Comment: Think about replacing the lifespan attribute with an attribute holding the expiration date of the object.

Comment: I see, that way i just compare against the value.  That makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Core Data fetch request can actually contain simple arithmetic expression.
So to find all objects where "created + lifespan  >= now",
the following works:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"created + lifespan >= %@", now];
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.
eg:

```
NSDate * yesterday = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-(60 * 60 * 24)];
NSPredicate * predicate = [[NSPredicate alloc] initWithFormat:@"dateCreated > %@", yesterday];
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Here is more info on writing predicates: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

Comment: the above assumes your object Foo has a "dateCreated" attribute which is an NSDate.

Comment: A day does not always have 24 hours.

Comment: True--but this demonstrates how to do the fetch.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Unfortunately, I just realized there's a part of the question i forgot to include.  Sorry for the incomplete question.  I'm changing my original question now to correctly describe my problem.